# Problem in using Scaffolding in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core-scaffolding

I get the following error when using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 8 when creating a view using scaffolding and using controller and view models. All packages are updated and Visual Studio is the latest version, and I have built many times and I have no errors. Please help me. My project is a few days old because of this issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` dependency in your project/solution?